# OCaml: order of input two values

Tags: arguments, ocaml

In functional language order of evaluation function arguments should have no sense.

However, even simplest programs could be not quite-functional. Here the code reads two integers and raises one into the power of other:

```
let pwr x y =
    let rec pwrx = function 0 -> 1 | y -> x * pwrx (y - 1)
    in pwrx y;;

print_int (pwr (read_int ()) (read_int ()));;
```

The code, obviously, reads the second argument first: if `5` and `4` are entered, result is `1024`.

I suppose problem is in mishandling the language and lack of understanding its ideology. How should I wrote such things properly? Should I read two values in separate lines before calling function?

```
let x = read_int();;
let y = read_int();;
print_int (pwr x y);;
```

It works but looks like bit overhead - isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not the lack of functional aspect of the language, but the fact that a feature like `read_line` is not functional per se since it relies on an external input from `stdin`.

You should use local declarations like you did (and it's even pointed out [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora029.html) on official documentation). There's no real overhead since they're just declarations.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to be part of a single function and use purely local variables the code would be:

```
let x = read_int() in
let y = read_int() in 
    print_int (pwr x y)
```

Generally, speaking, if you want to enforce a particular order, you should use let statements to do it.  It's slightly less pretty looking, but not everything can look elegant all the time, especially input and output in functional programming.